# В чем проблема python?

Tags: python

```
number=7
print("Я загадал число от 5 до 10")
guess=int(input("Bведите число:")
if guess==number
    print('Поздравляю ты угадал')
elif guess<number
    print('Нет,немного больше')
elif guess>number
    print('Нет,немного меньше')
```

Comment: Вы скобку в третьей строчке забыли.

Comment: Кстати, у Python нет проблем :D

Comment: @nomnoms12 есть одна :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Я обескуражен :/

Comment: @nomnoms12 несовместимость 2 и 3

Answer (score 1):

1) Пропущена закрывающая скобка в 3 строке: `)`
2) После окончания условия в инструкции `if` должно быть двоеточие: `:`

***Код:***

```py
number=7
print("Я загадал число от 5 до 10")
guess=int(input("Bведите число:"))
if guess==number:
    print('Поздравляю ты угадал')
elif guess<number:
    print('Нет,немного больше')
elif guess>number:
    print('Нет,немного меньше')
```